# If I, using a win10 ISO file, reset my OS. Would it delete my files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-systems

My dad's pc is acting slow, it's a windows 10. If I reset it's OS with an windows 10 ISO file, would it also reset it's apps and files and stuff on it's computer, or would it only reset the OS. And would it make the pc run faster?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Buying a SSD and cloning everything over with clonezilla or etc will do far more to speed your system than anything else.  If it has a HDD and its aging, resetting won;t change that.  If the PC is thermal throttling because of dust clogging the heat sink, reset won't fix that either.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a windows 10 ISO, as with windows 10, there is a system to reinstall windows 10 and keep your files in documents/desktop etc.

click start then type 'reset' - Look for the option to reset this PC, and if you go through that it will also ask 'keep my files' - windows will then reinstall and keep your files, but not any extra applications you have installed. Give that a go, and let me know how it went.

Answer (score 1):

An essential step, before resetting the computer, would be to
find out *why* is the computer slow.

A prime suspect is the disk, which might possibly be failing.
If the disk supports SMART, use a product to list its SMART attributes.
If you're unsure what they mean, add this data to your post so
we can see.
Some products that do that are
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) and
[CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Other checks you can do :

- Check how much free space you have on the disk - Windows needs
  this in order to function correctly
- Run `chkdsk`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Examine the Event Viewer for error messages
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours,
  if possible over-night.

Before doing anything, ensure that you have good backups of the
data on this computer. This is in case it is indeed the disk
that is failing.